# More number of lines of code inside a if loop and metrics

Tags: c#

I am writing a C# method that has an IF condition checked and 
if the condition is true, 
     i will execute 10 lines of code, 
else 
     i will execute only 2 lines.

ReSharper suggests that I should reverse the condition in the if loop so that the number of lines inside a if loop is less than the one in else loop.

Sample :

```
if(condition)
{
//      StatementBlock of 10 lines
}
else
{
//        StatementBlock of 2 lines
}
```

Kindly let me know the metrics / performance behind this as either way, we end up in having 2 blocks of code.

Comment: ReSharper suggests a lot of things, reverse it and see that it suggests to reverse it again. ReSharper suggests refactoring because it is what it does.

Comment: I don't think there's a difference in performance, but it can sometimes help developers read the logic of code where they can easily see the logic gate and both paths. If the first path is looooooong, they may have trouble tracking the code paths, or they may go too deep into the first block of code and forget (goldfish memory) about the conditions resulting in the second block. (Perhaps even better might be to separate the first block, and possibly second, into a separate private descriptively named method!) Regardless of what Resharper suggests, _just do what makes the most sense for you_.

Comment: I think the suggested change is more readable.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair: Hi Chris, Is it that the private static method code is like an Ngen'ed Code.

Comment: Just because ReSharper suggests a change doesn't mean that it's giving you the best option.  Not only should you consider whether it's actually a good change (I reject most LINQ approaches as I find them less readable and much harder to debug) but you should also look to see if the right answer is something else entirely.  In this case I think it is--Chris Sinclair had it right when he suggested splitting the 10 lines out.

Comment: @saravanan Not sure what that is. The private method can be static or instance (depends on the context of what the lines are doing). I simply mean that your code might be better off looking like `if (condition) DoThisDescriptiveThing(); else DoOtherDescriptiveThing();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't get any performance gain from switching the 2 blocks, however I think that your code is slightly more readable if you do

```
if a > b
    do 1
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
else 
    do 1
    do 2
```

is a little harder to read than

```
if b > a
   do 1
   do 2
else
   very
   long
   code
   that 
   might 
   require 
   scrolling
   to 
   read
```